# React Native : messaging().onMessage is not triggered very first time app launched in iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to handle foreground firebase messages.
But messaging().onMessage is not triggered very first time app launched in iOS. This is working fine in Android.
Exact scenario is:

- First time launch app : messaging().onMessage not triggered in iOS
- Close and reopen app : messaging().onMessage will trigger

````
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';

function FCMReadInForeGround() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      Alert.alert('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, []);
}

export default FCMReadInForeGround;```
````

Answer (score 0):

i hope this help you. i have same problem, and the im looking documentation ios messaging setup.

here the link : https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage/ios-setup .

in my case I haven't Linking APNs with FCM (iOS)

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `setBackgroundMessageHandler` outside your component.

```js
// Register background handler
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
  try {
    console.log('Remote notification', remoteMessage)
  } catch (err) { console.log(err) }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getInitialNotification` https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/notifications#handling-interaction

```js
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging';
...
  useEffect(() => {
    messaging()
      .getInitialNotification()
      .then(remoteMessage => {
        if (remoteMessage) {
          console.log(
            'Notification caused app to open from quit state:',
            remoteMessage.notification,
          );
        }
      });
  }, []);
```